# How to take a sample in R such that the original proportion remains the same

Tags: r, database, analytics, sampling

i want a sample from a data such that the original proportion of the variables remains the same. For example if in my original data, there were 1000 values of which there were 100 values of a, 800 values of b, and 100 values of c. if i am to take a sample of say 100 values from this original data, it should have 10 values of a, 80 values of b and 10 values of c. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The `tidyverse` package(s) have some nice functions that help with this.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(Group = c(rep("a", 100), rep ("b", 800), rep("c", 100)),
               Value = runif(1000))

sampledData <- data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  sample_frac(0.1)
```

We create a very simple example of your dataset, with random uniform values and 3 groups, 100 from `a`, 800 from `b` and 100 from `c`.

Using the function `group_by` we group the data on that group variable, so that when we use the function `sample_frac`, the function is executed on all groups separately.

We can check this with `table`:

```
> table(sampledData$Group)

 a  b  c 
10 80 10
```

**Note**:

This answer uses the `tidyverse` pipe operator `%>%`, this is equivalent to:

```
sampledData <- sample_frac(group_by(data, Group), 0.1)
```